# Splunk post-process timecharts display "no results found" in dashboard, but query on its own is fine

Tags: splunk

I have a simple-xml splunk dashboard with a base query, and two post-processing queries inheriting from the base. However, when I load the dashboard, it always says "No results found." When I click the "Open in search" button, the results show as expected. Also, when I take out of base search and just throw the entire search into both panels, the charts display as expected. Anyone know what's going on here?

Here's the dashboard xml that isn't working:

```
<dashboard>
    <label>Test Dashboard</label>
    <description>This is a test</description>
        <search id="base">
            <query>
                index=app sourcetype=tracelog splunk_server_group=prod 
                eventName=business:Logout
                (NOT description="*invalid username or password*")
                NOT code="6703" NOT code="6704" NOT "code=8006" NOT "code=6900" NOT "code=6000" 
            </query>
        </search>
    <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Test chart 1</title>
            <chart>
                <search base="base">
                    <query>
                        search success=false AND agent=true | timechart count by errors
                    </query>
                </search>
                <option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
                <option name="charting.chart">column</option>
            </chart>
        </panel>
    </row>
        <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Test chart 2</title>
            <chart>
                <search base="base">
                    <query>
                        search success=false AND agent=false | timechart count by errors
                    </query>
                </search>
                <option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
                <option name="charting.chart">column</option>
            </chart>
        </panel>
    </row>
</dashboard>
```

However, if I combine the queries and get rid of the base query as seen below, it works:

```
<dashboard>
    <label>Test Dashboard</label>
    <description>This is a test</description>
    <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Test chart 1</title>
            <chart>
                <search>
                    <query>
                        index=app sourcetype=tracelog splunk_server_group=prod 
                        eventName=business:Logout
                        (NOT description="*invalid username or password*")
                        NOT code="6703" NOT code="6704" NOT "code=8006" NOT "code=6900" NOT "code=6000" 
                        | search success=false AND agent=true | timechart count by errors
                    </query>
                </search>
                <option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
                <option name="charting.chart">column</option>
            </chart>
        </panel>
    </row>
        <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Test chart 2</title>
            <chart>
                <search>
                    <query>
                        index=app sourcetype=tracelog splunk_server_group=prod 
                        eventName=business:Logout
                        (NOT description="*invalid username or password*")
                        NOT code="6703" NOT code="6704" NOT "code=8006" NOT "code=6900" NOT "code=6000" 
                        | search success=false AND agent=false | timechart count by errors
                    </query>
                </search>
                <option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
                <option name="charting.chart">column</option>
            </chart>
        </panel>
    </row>
</dashboard>
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the mentioned base search is a non-transforming search and splunk forgets about the fields in the post-processing.

It the mentioned case, the base search has to be changed to

```
<query>
     index=app sourcetype=tracelog splunk_server_group=prod 
     eventName=business:Logout
     (NOT description="*invalid username or password*")
     NOT code="6703" NOT code="6704" NOT "code=8006" NOT "code=6900" NOT "code=6000"
     | fields success agent errors
</query>
```

Instead of specifying the fields you could also use `| table *` to propagate all fields.

See also: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/Savedsearches#Best_practices - topic: No results returned

> If the base search is a non-transforming search, you must explicitly state in the base search what fields will be used in the post-process search using the `| fields` command. For example, if your post-process search will search for the top selling buttercup game categories over time, you would use a search command similar to the following.